# Problem with Thesis Template

Tags: packages, compiling, thesis

I'm starting to write my PhD thesis and I want to use this template by Lorenzo Pantieri: 
http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/TesiModerna.zip

So I downloaded the file and I opened it on TexMaker 4.4.1 under Mac OS 10.8.5, I didn't modify anything of the file nor in the code.

Then I compiled and some errors occurred. I tried to figured out why, I also wrote to the author some days ago, but he didn't reply to me so far.

Do you guys face the same problem with that file?
How can I face it?

[image]

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Please provide a MWE which shows your problem

Comment: Thank you guys, I provided a screenshot which I think could explain more of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the zip-file includes a `.bbl` that probably was generated by older versions of `biber`/`biblatex`. Delete the `.bbl` file and recompile, then it should work fine.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!
Grazie mille! It worked!